# Equation Break for the next page

Tags: math-mode

My Question is i have document which contains some text and equations. The problem is how can i break a long equation whithout disturbing the equality sign in the next age.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum,lineno}



\begin{document}
Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text.
Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text.
Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text.
Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text.
Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text.
\begin{align*}
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b\\
a&=b
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: use `\allowdisplaybreaks` eg in the document preamble

Comment: Sir, where i need to add \allowdisplaybreaks ? I can't get

Comment: anywhere after `\usepackage{amsmath}` and before `\begin{align`